# The cars won't delete or delete others cars what do I do (Roblox)

Tags: roblox

How do I make this code delete only the player's car when they click it, so that it doesn't delete some other car when someone else spawns their car?

```
local model = game.Workspace.Car --or whatever the path to the model of your car is
local button = script.Parent --or whatever the path to your button is
local destination = Vector3.new(x, y, z) --the 3D coordinates of where you'd like the car to spawn

local function spawnCar()
     model:MoveTo(destination) --use this if you want to move the car that's in the dealership
     model:Clone():MoveTo(destination) --use this if you want to make a copy of the car and move that
end

button.MouseButton1Down:connect(spawnCar) --notice it's "spawnCar", NOT "spawnCar()"
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are new to Stack Overflow!

I assume you are asking how to rewrite the code so only the car's owner can delete the car.

I'd just like to point out an error you are making; in the spawnCar function, you have told the car to move the the location, then clone itself and move again. This will result in two cars at the same point so I recommend you choose one or the other.

To answer your question, we could start by adding a ClickDetector in to a Part in the car. Name this part "DeleteButton". Then, create a part, put it somewhere on your car, insert a ClickDetector (Right Click the Part -> Insert -> ClickDetector) in to the part and put the part inside the Car Model. I'd also like you to insert a StringValue in to the model (Right Click -> Insert -> StringValue).

Next, open up your script and we will get started.

Here is some edited code below, that will help you add a Delete function for only the owner of the car.

```
local model = game.Workspace.Car --or whatever the path to the model of your car is
local playerValue = game.Workspace.Car.StringValue
local deleteButton = game.Workspace.Car.DeleteButton
local button = script.Parent --or whatever the path to your button is
local destination = Vector3.new(x, y, z) --the 3D coordinates of where you'd like the   car to spawn

local function spawnCar(Clicker)
     model:MoveTo(destination) --use this if you want to move the car that's in the  dealership
     model:Clone():MoveTo(destination) --use this if you want to make a copy of the car and move that
     playerValue.Value = Clicker.Name -- sets the person who clicked's name to the value.
end

local function deleteCar(Clicker)
     if playerValue.Value == Click.Name then -- if the players name is the same as the owner's name
            model:Destroy() -- destroy the car if it is
     end
end


button.MouseClick:Connect(spawnCar) --notice it's "spawnCar", NOT "spawnCar()"
deleteButton.MouseClick:Connect(deleteCar) -- notice it's "deleteCar", NOT "deleteCar()"
```

So to conclude, this is what I have edited: I have added two new variables, for the path of a player value and a new button Part; I have added a line to the code that sets the player value to the player's name; I have created a function that detects if the player's name is the same as the value, it will delete the car. Finally, I have added a line to say when the Detector is clicked, it will do the delete car function.

Corrections I have made that you need to watch out for:

-> MouseButton1Click/Down is for GUIs, use MouseClick!

-> Pick one or the other (you moved a car twice!)

-> You still need to set WHERE you want the car to spawn in the destination line, an example would be     `local destination = Vector3.new(1, 1, 1)` etc.

Make sure to upvote this post if it helped you and if this answered your question, don't forget to hit the tick and mark this as correct!

I'm happy to help in the comments, Ross.

Comment: I feel like the spawner type I'm using isn't right now I found this code but it has the same problem over again it deletes other peoples cars and only one person can get a car. but im still checking over the spawnersystem = script.Parent

model = system.Station --

backup = model:Clone()

regen = system.Regen



function checkRegen()

 if regen.Value == 1 then

  model:remove()

  wait(1)

  model = backup:Clone()

  model.Parent = system

  model:MakeJoints()

 end

end

regen.Changed:connect(checkRegen)

Comment: @Morgun1127 Alright, found your issue. When you "clone" the car, you are keeping it as the same name. Since everyone has the same car name, in the same location, the code deletes all models in Workspace called "Car", that is everyone's. You can solve this by replacing the entire spawnCar and deleteCar function with the following in this pastebin; https://pastebin.com/i76nZESW